# Time clock at the footline of a beamer slide is not adjusted in the middle if compiling with XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, tdclock

I'm adding a title clock in the foot line of a `beamer` slide, if I compile it with pdfLaTeX it works fine; while the clock doesn't align in the middle vertically if compiling with XeLaTeX. How can I fix this.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=1]{tdclock}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{Title}
\author{Authors}
\institute{Institute}
\date[\initclock\tddate\ \ \tdtime]{\today}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this is not `beamer`-specific: you'll see it with any class. I think it's linked to the `(x)dvipdfm(x)` driver family, as the docs warn that `tdclock` only works with PDF mode/`dvips`.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the [`tdclock` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tdclock/tdclock-doc.pdf):

> The package requires `hyperref`, `xkeyval` and `xcolor` packages. It works with `PDFLATEX` as well as with `LATEX→DviPs→Ps2pdf` sequence. In documents generated by `Dvipdfm`, the clock does not work properly.

---

In case you are using `xelatex` for special fonts not available with pdflatex, tdclock also seems to work fine with `lualatex` which also lets you use special fonts.

Answer (score 2):

The `tdclock` implementation is overly complicated and error-prone.

Here is an alternative implementation that works properly with all TeX engines and back-ends:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Digital Clock Implementation
%
% Usage:
%
%   % set-up (defaults)
%   \def\clockfont{Helvetica} % or Times
%   \def\clockfontscale{0.93}
%   \def\clockformat{yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss}
%   \def\clockrefresh{1000} % milli-seconds
%
%   % insert clock
%   \digiclock
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\clockPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\clockPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\clockAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\def\clock@start#1#2#3{%
  function showtime#3(){%
    this.getField("digiclock.#3").value=util.printd("#1",new Date());%
    this.dirty=false;%
  }%
  showtime#3();%
  var digiclock#3=app.setInterval("showtime#3()",#2);%
}%
\newcounter{clock@num}%
\newlength\ex@height%
\newlength\clock@width%
\newlength\clock@height%
\def\digiclock{%
  \settowidth\clock@width{\clockformat}%
  \settoheight\clock@height{\clockformat}%
  \settoheight\ex@height{X}%
  \extractcolorspec{.}\clock@tempb% current color (\setcolor{...})
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\clock@tempb{rgb}\clock@tempb%
  \edef\clock@tempa{\expandafter\clock@rgbcomp\clock@tempb\@nil}%
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \makebox[\clockfontscale\clock@width][l]{%
      \clockPdfAnnot{\clockfontscale\clock@width}%
                    {\clockfontscale\clock@height}{\clockfontscale\clock@height}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Tx/T (digiclock.\theclock@num) /Ff 1
        /DA (/\clockfont\space 0 Tf \clock@tempa\space rg)
        /MK<</BC []/BG []>>
        /Q 2
        /BS <</W 1/S/S>>
        /AA <<
          /PO <</S/JavaScript/JS(\clock@start{\clockformat}{\clockrefresh}{\theclock@num})>>
          /PC <</S/JavaScript/JS(app.clearInterval(digiclock\theclock@num);)>>
        >>
      }%
    }%
    \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\ex@height depth 0.5\ex@height%
  }%
  \clockAppendToFields{\clockPdfLastAnn}%
  \stepcounter{clock@num}%
}
\def\clock@rgbcomp#1,#2,#3\@nil{#1 #2 #3}
\makeatother
%default settings
\def\clockfont{Helvetica}
\def\clockfontscale{0.93}
\def\clockformat{yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss}
\def\clockrefresh{1000}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usetheme{Madrid}
\date[\def\clockfontscale{1.1}\def\clockformat{HH:MM:ss}\digiclock]{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \LARGE current date \& time: \digiclock
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `tdclock` and `xelatex` are not compatible.
I try to change the packet itself and it's my temporary solution.

In file `tdclock.sty`, change the `\def` of `\clockfield` and `\pdfcolon` may fix this problem for xelatex.

I just make box bigger.

old:

```
\def\pdfcolon{%
\clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true, name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,value=:]{}}%
\vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-0.4pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 0.90\clock@fontsize{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}%
{\mbox{\TextField[name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,
readonly=true,value=:]{}\kern-0.90\clock@fontsize\kern\a@one pt\kern \b@one\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
}

\def\clockfield#1{%
\clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true, name=#1, width=1.31\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize]{}}%
\vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-\a@a pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 1.31\clock@fontsize{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}%
{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}{\mbox{\TextField[name=#1, width=1.31\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,readonly=true,
value={}]{}\kern-1.31\clock@fontsize\kern\a@a pt\kern \b@b\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
}
```

new:

```
\def\pdfcolon{%
\clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true, name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=1.2\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,value=:]{}}%
\vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-0.4pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 0.90\clock@fontsize{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}%
{\mbox{\TextField[name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=1.2\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,
readonly=true,value=:]{}\kern-0.90\clock@fontsize\kern\a@one pt\kern \b@one\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
}

\def\clockfield#1{%
\clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true, name=#1, width=1.6\clock@fontsize, height=1.2\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize]{}}%
\vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-\a@a pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 1.6\clock@fontsize{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}%
{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}{\mbox{\TextField[name=#1, width=1.6\clock@fontsize, height=1.2\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,readonly=true,
value={}]{}\kern-1.6\clock@fontsize\kern\a@a pt\kern \b@b\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
}
```

[image]